# Why are we now getting 'hot network questions'?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange

I notice that we are now getting a bar listing hot questions from across the SE network. I thought we'd settled for no cross-site advertising in MO2.0.

Comment: Sorry; this appears to simply have been overlooked when we were rolling this out everywhere else.

Comment: @Shog9 - would you mind posting this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Easier to just edit Scott's answer. So, done. Go ahead and accept ;-)

Comment: @Shog9: I'm not sure I remember the details of MO2.0, but should any MO question appear as a hot question for other sites as well?

Comment: So far as I'm aware, there aren't any restrictions on that; the logic for it hasn't changed, at any rate. @Asaf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I asked the SE folks and they promptly fixed the problem, noting that it was due to a simple oversight when rolling out the feature to the rest of the network.

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this as "Not an answer". :-)

Comment: This should have been a comment, and Shog9's comment should have been an answer!

Comment: Ah, tea. :-)...

Comment: I've just seen an advertisement for a MO post on MSE: